# Collaborative password storage solution for web developers

Tags: password-manager

## Context

We currently use a spreadsheet to store our clients passwords. This is getting bigger and bigger and seems that whenever you want to find something you lose time and it's pretty much frustrating. We were considering creating our own password storing system but I thought that maybe it's better to ask you guys first.

## Requirements

- Roles determine what passwords can be seen. For instance, I can see the passwords for the customers I am in charge of, but my colleague can not see them
- For each customer, store passwords for various activities, for instance cpanel/ftp/db/domains/platform admins
- Easy way to add passwords
- Easy way to search for passwords (preferably live search)

Comment: There are plenty of available password managers.  I think you need to be a little more specific about your needs.

Comment: Do you have an OS preference?  Are you looking for free or commercial software recommendations?

Comment: Are you sure that you should even **have** your clients' passwords?

Comment: It looks like that you need CRM, not just password storage since you have to store other client information (eg. telephone number, emails etc.)

Answer (score 5):

I would highly recommend open source (and ideally audited) software for [security reasons](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_software_security)!

Nearly every common password safe fits your needs, so you should be more specific for better suggestions.

---

But for now I would recommend [KeePass](http://keepass.info/) <s>and/or [KeePassX](https://www.keepassx.org/)</s>. With its countless [ports](http://keepass.info/download.html) you are platform independent and don't have to hand over your passwords to a cloud service!

---

### Update

KeePassX was forked by [KeePassXC](https://keepassxc.org/), whose new and sightly improved [features](https://keepassxc.org/project/) are now available on all platforms, so it may be the best choice.

Comment: I tried KeePass but failed to sync the databases between my PC and my Android. Can you give me any useful tips form your experience? I tried it with some kind of plugin on the desktop program to export the database to dropbox and then import it on the mobile app. But that plugin is already giving me errors. Can this exchange of a simple file also be done via my FTP? I hope so...

Comment: for sure!!! - all the data are stored in a normal file (kdb/kdbx)... so you can do everything with it, you like to! -- heck... you can also exchange it via floppy! **;-)** --> i don't use any plugins at all... i exchange my password-files like all my other files via WebDAV and/or FTP.

Comment: **BUT** keep one thing in mind: not all ports support both [versions (kdb/kdbx) of the password-file](http://keepass.info/help/v2/version.html)! - so first have a look at all ports you want to use and then decide which file-version you have to use...

Answer (score 2):

My team has been using [1Password](https://agilebits.com/onepassword) for password management, and I highly recommend it for several reasons.

- Secure
- Searchable - you can also create tags and folders for passwords
- Cross-platform - Supports Mac, Windows, iOS, and Android
- Syncs through Dropbox
- Supports wide variety of login types - passwords, servers, ftp, etc.

1Password offers [business licenses](https://agilebits.com/store/business), but if cost is a concern, you can get by with a single license (for an admin user) and use trial licenses for other members of the team. Those other members would only be able to access passwords, not create new ones.

Comment: Can I create different fields for each entry? Like... can I add the user, password and url of the cpanel AND the domain name with it's password? Or only user/password combinations?

Comment: Yes - you can make custom fields for each entry.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [Passopolis](https://passopolis.com/). It is a fork of the (deprecated) Mitro.

It is a browser plugin so passwords are encrypted locally and saved in the cloud. You can also host an own server.

Answer (score 0):

From roboform.com

> Features
>
> Our features are built to directly address all critical points in the
>   password cycle, starting from password generation, to storing, reuse,
>   and sharing.

[More details about RoboForm](https://www.roboform.com/business/features)

[image: RoboForm screenshot 1]

---

[image: RoboForm screenshot 2]

---

[image: RoboForm screenshot 3]